# Typo3 6.1/6.2 compatibility with PHP 5.6

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-6.1.x

I'm getting mixed results when I search for this topic.
I need to upgrade my PHP-Version to 5.6.

I have an existing T3-Installation with Version 6.1.8 and am planning to upgrade another Version from 4.7 to 6.2 (can't go to 7 because of Templavoila [sic]).

So the question is: are T3 V 6.1.8 and 6.2.x compatible with PHP 5.6?

(I'm aware that I need to update the currently installed extensions that are running under 4.7 now).

I ran some tests on my localhost with PHP 5.6 and they went fine - just not sure if this will work «in the wild» as well...

Any clarification would be awesome ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo3's source code is [stored on Github](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/), so you can explore the version history very easily

Each version includes an INSTALL.md file, which details the requirements and compatibility.

The one for v6.2 is here: https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_6-2/INSTALL.md

Reading this file, it says:

> Server system requirements
>
> PHP >5.3.7 up to 5.5 (PHP 5.4 or later recommended)

This implies that it is **not** compatible with PHP 5.6.

However, I suspect a more likely scenario is that it was simply released before PHP 5.6 was available, so they are just quoting "up to 5.5" because it was the highest version available at the time. There is very little in the way of breaking changes between PHP 5.5 and 5.6, so it is unusual for a package to work with 5.5 and not 5.6, particularly if it is a well-written and maintained package like Typo3.

I will note that Typo 6.2 is still being maintained (the last update in Github shows as just a few days ago), so given that PHP 5.6 is the most widely used PHP version as of right now, the chances are very high that it will have been updated to PHP 5.6 compatibility at some point, even if it it wasn't compatible when intially released.

So my gut instinct tells me that you should be okay with 5.6 if you want to risk it. However if you want certainty you will probably be better to follow their recommendation and stick with 5.5.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. «gut instinct» is nice and my gut actually tells me the same as your's does ;) It just isn't an option to stick with 5.5 as our hoster insists on upgrading to 5.6... May the T3-Gods be with me, then ;)

Comment: I actually wish more hosting companies would be so good at keeping their PHP version up-to-date. I get depressed by how many hosts are still running PHP versions that haven't been supported in years, so it's good to hear of one that is being a bit more pro-active, even if it's not totally convenient for you right at this moment. (you should also think yourself lucky that they're not pushing you to upgrade to to PHP 7, because that *does* have major breaking changes)

Comment: You should also consider asking your question on the Typo3 support forums, if you haven't already. I would imagine you're more likely to get a definitive answer from there.

Comment: Indeed - I'm actually happy with the hoster. The T3-Forums are - to put it mildly - a little lame. Getting answers there can be hard... Actually, I don't have a choice anyway. They'll upgrade the PHP-Version and I have to deal with it... praying right now ;)

Comment: In case you didn't see it already: [Backward incompatible changes from PHP 5.5 to 5.6](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.incompatible.php). There's really not a lot there. Certainly nothing that should be particularly worrying.

Comment: Wow - thanks again, Simba - really appreciate your effort!